# How Mode=TwoWay bindings submit the update?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

The textbox is bound to a ViewModel and if its content has been updated the ViewModel would submit the update to a source(normally db).

The XAML side should be like this.

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
   Text="{Binding Path=LowVoltage, StringFormat={}{0:N3}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
```

**Meanwhile, in the ViewModel, is it a good choice to do update like this?**

```
private float lowVoltage;
        public float LowVoltage
        {
            get { return this.lowVoltage; }
            set
            {
                if (this.lowVoltage != value)
                {
                    this.lowVoltage = value;

                    **//dbContext.Submit(); --here**
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("LowVoltage");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't choose to make database operations inside a property setter, better work with Commands, like access the ViewModel in the behind code LostFocus event handler and execute it or use EventTrigger in XAML.

```
<Grid xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SomeEvent">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=SomeCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Grid>
```